# Oracle Stored Procedure varray beyond count

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, varray

i've created 3 stored procedures. Each of their functions are : 
1. proc_insertleveluser -> insert into "leveluser" table and return the last id inserted 
2. proc_insertpermissiondtl -> insert into "permission_dtl" table and return the last id inserted 
3. proc_insert_relation_lpd -> insert into "lvl_permission_dtl" table with data provided from procedure 1 and 2

**proc_insertleveluser**

```
create or replace procedure proc_insertleveluser(level_desc varchar, level_ int, department_id varchar, r_id_level out int)
as
begin
  insert into leveluser (level_desc, level_, department_id) values (level_desc, level_, department_id)
  returning id_level into r_id_level;
  commit;
end;
```

**proc_insertpermissiondtl**

```
create or replace procedure proc_insertpermissiondtl(status_ int, entry_ int, view_ int, modify_ int, delete_ int, approval_ int, r_id_p_dtl out int)
as
begin
  insert into permission_dtl (status_, entry_, view_, modify_, delete_, approval_)
  values(status_, entry_, view_, modify_, delete_, approval_)
  returning id_p_dtl into r_id_p_dtl;
  commit;
end;
```

and **proc_insert_relation_lpd**

```
create or replace procedure proc_insert_relation_lpd(lu_level_desc varchar, lu_level_ int, lu_department_id varchar)
as
  r_id_level int;  /* r_ is for return */
  r_id_p_dtl int;  
  type arr_id_p_dtl is varray(13) of int;
  arraynya arr_id_p_dtl := arr_id_p_dtl();
begin
  proc_insertleveluser(lu_level_desc, lu_level_, lu_department_id, r_id_level); 
  for i in 1..arraynya.count loop  
    proc_insertpermissiondtl(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, r_id_p_dtl);
    arraynya(i) := r_id_p_dtl;
  end loop;

  /* more code here to insert to "lvl_permission_dtl" table */

  commit;
end;
```

When i execute the code, 1 record added into "leveluser" table, but not in "permission_dtl" table. It seems like the code inside the for loop was not executed.

What causes this? is the "arraynya" variable empty so the for loop won't execute? Or is there another problem? :)

Comment: Looking at `proc_insert_relation_lpd` there's nothing I can see which would put anything into `arraynya` prior to `arraynya` being using the the `for` statement. Were you expecting something else? Perhaps instead of using `arraynya.count` you meant to use `arraynya.limit`?

Comment: well, before the "begin" statement, i want to create empty varray "arraynya" from arr_id_p_dtl, which is a 13 length varray, and then fill every index inside "arraynya" with the value returned from proc_insertpermissiondtl on the for loop... is that the correct way?

Comment: As i said, I think you want to use `arraynya.limit` instead of `arraynya.count` in your `while` loop. Best of luck.

Comment: Oh, how stupid I am.. Thanks a lot, I got it now.. I thought ".count" is similar to ".length" or something like that.. :D

Comment: See [PL/SQL Reference: Using Collection Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#LNPLS00508) for documentation of the available collection methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've created an empty array so the `count` will be 0 when you get to the loop.  As Bob Jarvis points out, if you want to iterate through the loop 13 times, you'd want to use the `limit`, not the `count` of the array.

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  declare
  2    type arr_id_p_dtl is varray(13) of int;
  3    arraynya arr_id_p_dtl := arr_id_p_dtl();
  4  begin
  5    dbms_output.put_line( 'Count is ' || arraynya.count );
  6    dbms_output.put_line( 'Limit is ' || arraynya.limit );
  7    --
  8    -- This doesn't do anything since the count is 0
  9    --
 10    for i in 1..arraynya.count
 11    loop
 12      dbms_output.put_line( 'Count loop i=' || i );
 13    end loop;
 14    --
 15    -- This will iterate 13 times
 16    --
 17    for i in 1..arraynya.limit
 18    loop
 19      dbms_output.put_line( 'Limit loop i=' || i );
 20    end loop;
 21* end;
 22  /
Count is 0
Limit is 13
Limit loop i=1
Limit loop i=2
Limit loop i=3
Limit loop i=4
Limit loop i=5
Limit loop i=6
Limit loop i=7
Limit loop i=8
Limit loop i=9
Limit loop i=10
Limit loop i=11
Limit loop i=12
Limit loop i=13

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Hi @JustinCave unfortunately i still got a little problem here.. Why do i have to fill the varray first before i use it? In this case i have to type `arraynya arr_id_p_dtl := arr_id_p_dtl(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);` instead of `arraynya arr_id_p_dtl := arr_id_p_dtl();` Otherwise, it will throw "beyond count" error :( <br>
That will be awful if i have a 100 length of varray right?

Comment: @thekucays - Not sure I understand your question.  I'm hard-pressed to imagine a situation that I'd use a `varray` in the first place rather than a nested table or an associative array.  If you were going to declare a 100 element `varray` for some reason and wanted to initialize every element to 0, I'd simply write the loop that I did in my answer and initialize the elements that way.